# Embedding JSON Data into YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, yaml

I am writing a fixture for my table. And a one of the coloums takes in a JSON string as a value.

The problem is the fixture is not loading failing as:

```
Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing /home/saurajeet/code/dcbox/test/fixtures/hardware.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Please have a look at http://www.yaml.org/faq.html
The exact error was:
  ArgumentError: syntax error on line 145, col 73: `  portslist: [{"name":"ob1","port_num":0,"port_type":"network"},{"name":"ob2","port_nu'.....
```

Any solutions to this.

Comment: Do you have a paste of exactly the problematic file?  Which processor are you using?  The error report is that you have a *TAB* character, so it's very specific issue.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I believe taking it into quotes should do the trick:

```
portslist: '[{"name":"ob1","port_type" ... }]'
```

Comment: This makes the value be a string, so it's not really embedding.  If you want to do this, I'd use a block scalar and indent.

Comment: Strings are scalar type, but I get what you mean.

Comment: yeah ok, what about multi-line JSON?

Answer (score 71):

clarkevans' comment on the accepted answer suggested a better answer for long bits of JSON, because you can wrap the lines.  I looked up the [block scalar syntax](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#example-block-scalar-header) he mentioned, and thought I would include an example here:

```
portslist: >
  [{"name":"ob1","port_num":0,"port_type":"network"},
  {"name":"ob2","port_nu...
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/XkVEeVqakNv I am trying with this, but not working for me

Comment: This works. But is there a way in YAML where I can reference an external JSON file and set it as a value inside the YAML ?

Comment: Any one has idea how to reference an external JSON file inside yaml file. Also, above internal JSON is working for me.

Answer (score 24):

The `|` is also possible. For example.

```
MyObject:
  type: object
  example: |
    {
        "id": 54,
        "manufacturer": "ACME",
        "location": "New York",
        "createdAt": "2012-10-01 07:42:35.825565",
        "description": "test",
    }
```

Comment: what would be the **data type** of `example` property in that case?

Comment: @JobaDiniz [Multiline string with linebreaks preserved as `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/4179032)

Answer (score 12):

If you have the string, you can use as simple as Vlad Khomich mentioned:

```
portslist: '[{"name":"ob1","port_num":0,"port_type":"network"},...]'
```

If you are using ERB and have an object, you can use to_json and inspect to escape to a JSON string:

```
portslist: <%= [{name: 'ob1', port_num: 0, port_type: 'network'},...].to_json.inspect %>
```

And if you have a large JSON specification, you can store it in a separated file and load using Ruby, so you can keep your YAML file clean:

```
portslist: <%= File.read('/path/to/file.json').inspect %>
```

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of being complete: In case you're using [`ActiveRecord::Store`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html), you can load your data simply using YAML representation of the same data, even if it is a JSON store:

```
one:
  portslist:
    - 
      name: 'ob1'
      port_num: 0
      port_type: 'network'
    - 
      name: 'ob2'
      port_num: 1
      port_type: 'network'
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the wonderful interactive documentation and demo provided by [yaml-multiline.info](https://yaml-multiline.info). I've archived the text content below:

> There are two types of formats that YAML supports for strings: *block
> scalar* and *flow scalar* formats. (*Scalars* are what YAML calls
> basic values like numbers or strings, as opposed to complex types like
> arrays or objects.) Block scalars have more control over how they are
> interpreted, whereas flow scalars have more limited escaping support.
>
> ### Block Scalars
>
> A block scalar header has three parts:
>
> **Block Style Indicator**: The *[block style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style)* indicates how
> newlines inside the block should behave. If you would like them to be
> kept as newlines, use the **literal** style, indicated by a pipe
> (`|`). If instead you want them to be replaced by spaces, use
> the **folded** style, indicated by a right angle bracket (`>`). (To
> get a newline using the folded style, leave a blank line by
> putting *two* newlines in. Lines with extra indentation are also not
> folded.)
>
> **Block Chomping Indicator**: The *[chomping indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8112-block-chomping-indicator)* controls
> what should happen with newlines at the *end* of the string. The
> default, **clip**, puts a single newline at the end of the string. To
> remove all newlines, **strip** them by putting a minus sign (`-`)
> after the style indicator. Both clip and strip ignore how many
> newlines are actually at the end of the block; to **keep** them all
> put a plus sign (`+`) after the style indicator.
>
> **Indentation Indicator**: Ordinarily, the number of spaces you're using to indent a block will be automatically guessed from its first
> line. You may need a *[block indentation
> indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8111-block-indentation-indicator)* if
> the first line of the block starts with extra spaces. In this case,
> simply put the number of spaces used for indentation (between 1 and 9)
> at the end of the header.
>
> ### Flow Scalars
>
> (Ed. reformatted for SO)
>
> #### Double-quoted
>
> Escapes (like `\n`) work. In addition, newlines can be escaped to prevent them from being converted to a space. Newlines can also be added by leaving a blank line. Leading whitespace on lines is ignored.
>
> #### Single-quoted
>
> Escapes (like `\n`) don't do anything. Newlines can be added by leaving a blank line. Leading whitespace on lines is ignored.
>
> #### Plain
>
> Escapes (like `\n`) don't do anything. Newlines can be added by leaving a blank line. Additional leading whitespace is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In my table, the column **stripe_connect** is of type **JSONB** .  In the fixture, here is what worked.  Note that the outer single-quotes are necessary, but square brackets are not.  Everything between the single quotes is one long line.

```
 stripe_connect: '{"scope":"read_write", "livemode":false, "token_type":"bearer", "access_token":"sk_test_madeupvalue", "refresh_token":"rt_Ae29madeupvalueyX", "stripe_user_id":"acct_103yZabcdefg", "stripe_publishable_key":"pk_test_0HEOmadeupvalue"}'
```