# Autowire json value in springboot from yaml

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, yaml

How to read json as a string from a yaml file in spring boot application ?

> *I need to get the json as a string / json object.*

**Application.yml**

```
Shirt:
 rest:
  booking:
   invoiceAddress: {"name":"VIA Pics AB","address1":"VIA Pics AB","address2":"Mejerivägen 3","zipCode":"11743","city":"STOCKHOLM","countryCode":"SE","email":"w.ho@Pics.fr"}
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationServiceClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${Shirt.rest.booking.invoiceAddress}")
    private String invoiceAddress;

    @Bean
    public String getInvoiceAddress(){
        System.out.println(invoiceAddress);
        return this.invoiceAddress;
    }
}
```

Also tried @JsonProperty but no idea whether my usage was wrong or not !

**Note:**
I am not ready to change the json as a list because more jsons (of invoiceAddress) to come and I will have to make list for each. So it's easy for me if the json can be copied as it is to the yaml file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532840/embedding-json-data-into-yaml-file/9532944#9532944

Comment: you haven't posted your problem/error! Kindly post the `stack trace` or `error log`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding JSON Data into YAML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532840/embedding-json-data-into-yaml-file)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want as a plan string you should add this value between single quote 'your value.' in your yml file

```
Shirt:
 rest:
  booking:
   invoiceAddress: '{"name":"VIA Pics AB","address1":"VIA Pics AB","address2":"Mejerivägen 3","zipCode":"11743","city":"STOCKHOLM","countryCode":"SE","email":"w.ho@Pics.fr"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your yml file as below:

```
Shirt.rest.booking:
   invoiceAddress: "\"name\":\"VIA Pics AB\",\"address1\":\"VIA Pics AB\",\"address2\":\"Mejerivägen 3\",\"zipCode\":\"11743\",\"city\":\"STOCKHOLM\",\"countryCode\":\"SE\",\"email\":\"w.ho@Pics.fr\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes escapes all the special characters in the values of YAML properties.
Just try adding to the string into single quotes 'PropertiesValue'.

E.g :

```
invoiceAddress: '{"name":"VIA Pics AB","address1":"VIA Pics AB","address2":"Mejerivägen 3","zipCode":"11743","city":"STOCKHOLM","countryCode":"SE","email":"w.ho@Pics.fr"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Shirt:
 rest:
  booking:
   invoiceAddress: >
    {"name":"VIA Pics AB","address1":"VIA Pics AB","address2":"Mejerivägen 3","zipCode":"11743","city":"STOCKHOLM","countryCode":"SE","email":"w.ho@Pics.fr"}
```

@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17093553/2929352