# How to specify nested json body in POST request

Tags: load-testing, artillery

I'm trying to set Artillery config to be able to send nested JSON body. This is how my configuration looks like:

```
config:
  target: <URL>
  phases:
    - duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 20
  processor: "./input-parser.js"
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - function: "parseJsonFile"
    - post:
        url: /workflow-instance
        headers:
           Content-Type: "application/json"
        json:
          name: "{{ name }}"
          namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
          template_name: "{{ template_name }}"
          attributes: "{{ attributes }}"
    - get:
        url: "/workflow-instance/status?name={{ template_name }}&namespace={{ namespace }}"
```

I have a problem with "attributes" because the content of attributes is:

```
{ pod_name: 'POD_NAME', port: 'PORT_NUMBER' }
```

So basically, this will not work:

```
attributes: "{ pod_name: 'POD_NAME', port: 'PORT_NUMBER' }"
```

as well as this:

```
attributes:
  pod_name: 'POD_NAME'
  port: 'PORT_NUMBER'
```

I didn't found good examples for this particular case in Artillery docs.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround worked for me [Embedding JSON Data into YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532840/embedding-json-data-into-yaml-file)

Then you'd have to change your `attributes` for:

```
attributes: '{ pod_name: "POD_NAME", port: "PORT_NUMBER" }'
```

I'm using:

```
Artillery: 1.7.9
Artillery Pro: not installed (https://artillery.io/pro)
Node.js: v14.6.0
OS: darwin/x64
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers looking for hardcoding nested JSON, this worked for me:

```
...
scenarios:
  -
    flow:
      -
        post:
          url: "/"
          json:
            text: {"filter": {"enabled": true}}
```